# Como agir quando não se tem certeza se a resposta dada está correta?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, respostas

Fiquei muito empolgado quando soube do SOpt, pois sempre utilizei o SOen, não como um membro, mais sim como uma pessoa qualquer que realiza pesquisas no Google e acaba caindo nele (meu inglês ainda não é satisfatório para responder as perguntas lá).

Então comecei a fazer parte do SOpt, respondi algumas perguntas até chegar a essa [Loop para afectar todos os registos de uma tabela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44017/), onde aparentemente era um simples *loop* que com o passar dos dias começou a ficar complicado, não pela lógica, mas sim pelo código.

Gostaria de saber se a minha atitude nessa pergunta foi correta ou errada, pois respondi a pergunta sem ter certeza se resultado dela está correto, devido ao fato do código que o AP postou ser complicado de se analisar aqui.

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta...

Comment: eu respondi a pergunta sem ter certeza se o resultado dela está correto, porque o código que a pessoa postou é complicado de se analisar aqui

Comment: Eu sugeria editar pelo menos o título desta pergunta, está ambíguo e no futuro não serve para fechar outras perguntas com este mesmo assunto pois será difícil estabelecer uma relação...

Comment: por mim tudo bem, só não tenho ideia de qual título colocar

Comment: @Zuul, alterei o título e coloquei a duvida direto na pergunta, se tiver alguma outra sugestão, fique a vontade para alterar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Creio que você encontrou um caso onde o(a) **A**utor(a) da **P**ergunta (AP) não quer apenas uma resposta objetiva para um problema específico ou um direcionamento para resolver o problema, mas a solução pronta e mastigada.

Ocorrem alguns casos desse tipo por aqui com certa frequência, geralmente com muitos comentários e uma notificação para os moderadores em decorrência disso.

É importante você considerar o seguinte:

## Somos voluntários

Você não está obrigado a fazer tudo o que for solicitado. Ninguém é obrigado a responder nada. Estamos aqui porque queremos, certo?

Não há nada de errado em impor educadamente alguns limites pessoais para como você gasta seu tempo.

## Não temos bola de cristal

Muitas vezes o AP pede coisas a mais que não estavam na pergunta original ou que estavam mal explicadas.

Se sua resposta não atendeu ao que realmente o AP queria, você **deve** solicitar para que ele(a) edite sua pergunta devidamente.

Caso não queira mais investir tempo nisso, pode remover sua resposta.

Lembre-se apenas de ser educado e paciente, nem sempre esses problemas são por má vontade.

## Evite sair muito do escopo

Existem casos onde você responde bem à pergunta e o AP pede alguns extras. Por exemplo, a pergunta era sobre o banco de dados, depois ele pediu para você ver também a tela.

Isso é ruim por vários motivos. Oriente o AP a fazer uma nova pergunta se houver alguma dúvida ou problema adicional.

Dessa forma tudo fica mais organizado e útil para quem visitar o site depois.

## Nem sempre acertamos

Há casos onde achamos que uma solução responde à pergunta, mas na realidade o problema era diferente. Pode ser um problema de interpretação, de falta de clareza ou porque "chutamos" mesmo.

Isso é normal, desde é claro que não seja um "chute" completamente "no escuro", do tipo que você não tem ideia do que está falando.

Quando isso ocorrer, você pode mudar a resposta sem problemas, mas não sinta-se obrigado a isso.

Pedir desculpas e remover a resposta é sempre uma opção.

## Deixe o sistema ajudar você

Se a pergunta não está clara, oriente o AP a melhorá-la.

Se não dá para entender o que o AP realmente quer, peça esclarecimentos em comentários.  Se der para entender mais ou menos, você mesmo pode fazer uma edição para melhorar. Se estiver muito ruim, vote para fechar como "não está claro".

Seu o AP está pedindo muita coisa ao mesmo tempo, sugiro para ele focar em um ponto e colocar os demais em outras perguntas. Caso ele não o faça e ninguém esteja disposto ou não seja possível dar uma resposta satisfatória, vote para fechar como "amplo demais".

## Porém, não use o sistema contra as pessoas

Apenas um alerta quanto a tópico anterior:

> Evite negativar ou votar para fechar qualquer pergunta ou resposta que você não gostar por alguma razão, sem que você a tenha entendido ou avaliado devidamente.

Ocorre com frequência que perguntas são fechadas porque as pessoas não se dão ao trabalho de ler corretamente.

Se não estiver disposto, deixe para outras pessoas a oportunidade de responder.

Comment: +1 grande resposta utluiz. Eu cada vez mais tento passar a frente aquilo que não sei ou tenho dúvidas. As vezes também erro, até porque errar é humano, mas tento sempre só comentar/responder/fechar/editar o que percebo realmente.

Comment: obrigado pela orientação, fiz uma última tentativa, se não conseguir, vou remover a resposta e deixar orientações para o AP

Comment: @MateusAlexandre Vale a pena ver também esta discussão: [O que fazer quando o O.P muda sua pergunta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1682/74). Tem muita pergunta que o autor vai editando e ela muda consideravelmente, *invalidando respostas existentes*. É um problema diferente do que você mencionou, mas relacionado.

Comment: @bfavaretto, realmente, creio que não seja o caso, pois as alterações feitas foram para completar o código, mas mesmo assim vale a leitura, quanto a pergunta em questão, optei por remover minha resposta

Comment: **Deixe o sistema ajudar você**. Precisamente. O que o @utluiz descreveu é absolutamente correto. Se a pergunta pode ser melhorada, incentive o autor a melhorá-la ou melhore-a você mesmo. Peça esclarecimentos, contexto, reescreva partes que estão confusas. Uma boa pergunta é benéfica à sua resposta. De que adianta um lindo tratado em resposta a uma pergunta que ninguém entendeu direito? Como alguém vai saber que você resolveu o problema de maneira excepcional se não dá pra saber qual era o problema?